# Adding secondary DNS IP to workstations with GPOs?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

If I have a new DC running Windows Server 2008R2, which is obviously running DNS, is it possible to add the IP address of the new DC to all workstations as a secondary DNS server?

Currently we have one DC using the IP of 192.168.1.50, I have added another DC with the IP of 192.168.1.60.

Each workstation currently has 192.168.1.50 as it's primary DNS server and blank for the secondary.

Is there a group policy setting that allows me to add the secondary DNS IP to each workstation automagically?

Comment: Why not just change it in DHCP??

Comment: @Chris has your answer. Unless there is a reason that this can't be done.

Comment: Sadly each workstation must have a static IP address and no DHCP can be used due to a vet management system which is maintained by an external vendor.

Comment: DHCP reservations can be used to assign the same IP to a computer every time it requests one. Centralize management goodness; static IP for evil applications.

Comment: @Chris do you know of any tutorials or documentation for setting that kind of thing up? I presume it works by setting the desired ip against the mac address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Group Policy setting for DNS.  I haven't used it before, but it's fully listed out with all options.

Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Network > DNS Client

From there, you can set your DNS servers and any other DNS information you want.
EDIT: you can add multiple DNS IP addresses to the DNS Servers entry by putting a space between each IP address.

EDIT: This GPO setting only works for Win XP computers.